# pandas iterrows() skip rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary-comprehension

I am using this code below to iterate over my dataframe data

Input:

```
dataframe1 = pandas.read_csv("bday.csv")
print (dataframe1)
```

Output:

```
nombre             email  mes  dia
0      A  adasd1@gmail.com   11   29
1      B  adasd2@gmail.com   11   28
2      C  adasd3@gmail.com   12   15
3      D  adasd4@gmail.com   12   11
4      E  adasd5@gmail.com   12   15
5      F  adasd6@gmail.com   11   13
6      G  adasd7@gmail.com    9    7
7      H  adasd8@gmail.com    1   30
8      I  adasd9@gmail.com    4   19`
```

then i use python comprehension for generate a dictionary

Input:

```
dict_bday = {(row["mes"],row["dia"]):row for index,row in dataframe1.iterrows()}

print(dict_bday)
```

Output:

```
{(11, 29): nombre                   A
    email     adasd1@gmail.com
    mes                     11
    dia                     29
    Name: 0, dtype: object, (11, 28): nombre                   B
    email     adasd2@gmail.com
    mes                     11
    dia                     28
    Name: 1, dtype: object, (12, 15): nombre                   E
    email     adasd5@gmail.com
    mes                     12
    dia                     15
    Name: 4, dtype: object, (12, 11): nombre                   D
    email     adasd4@gmail.com
    mes                     12
    dia                     11
    Name: 3, dtype: object, (11, 13): nombre                   F
    email     adasd6@gmail.com
    mes                     11
    dia                     13
    Name: 5, dtype: object, (9, 7): nombre                   G
    email     adasd7@gmail.com
    mes                      9
    dia                      7
    Name: 6, dtype: object, (1, 30): nombre                   H
    email     adasd8@gmail.com
    mes                      1
    dia                     30
    Name: 7, dtype: object, (4, 19): nombre                   I
    email     adasd9@gmail.com
    mes                      4
    dia                     19
    Name: 8, dtype: object}
```

In the generated dictionary the information is not displayed correctly, and some indexes are also missing.What could be the problem?

Comment: Dictionary do not allow duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how you expect the Dictionary to be formed and displayed, but this might be nearer what you want:

```
dict_bday = {(row["mes"],row["dia"]): list(row.values) for index,row in dataframe1.iterrows()}
for entry in dict_bday.items():
    print(entry[0], entry[1])
```

gives

```
(11, '29') ['A', 'adasd1@gmail.com', 11, '29']
(11, '28') ['B', 'adasd2@gmail.com', 11, '28']
(12, '15') ['E', 'adasd5@gmail.com', 12, '15']
(12, '11') ['D', 'adasd4@gmail.com', 12, '11']
(11, '13') ['F', 'adasd6@gmail.com', 11, '13']
(9, '7') ['G', 'adasd7@gmail.com', 9, '7']
(1, '30') ['H', 'adasd8@gmail.com', 1, '30']
(4, '19`') ['I', 'adasd9@gmail.com', 4, '19`']
```

If you want to see all Entries including duplicates then don't use a Dictionary using `mes  dia` as keys because repeated keys are not allowed. For example you could use:

```
df1 = dateframe1.set_index(['mes', 'dia'])

print(df1)
```

which gives:

```
    nombre             email
mes dia                         
11  29       A  adasd1@gmail.com
    28       B  adasd2@gmail.com
12  15       C  adasd3@gmail.com
    11       D  adasd4@gmail.com
    15       E  adasd5@gmail.com
11  13       F  adasd6@gmail.com
9   7        G  adasd7@gmail.com
1   30       H  adasd8@gmail.com
4   19       I  adasd9@gmail.com
```

Comment: Is there a way to display all entries, even repeated ones?

Comment: A Dictionary cannot have duplicate keys; a repeated key will overwrite the previous one (your E overwrites C). Of course there is no reason to convert the DF to a Dictionary if what you want is to display all; there are various ways to do this depending on what exactlly you want. See example in edited answer above.